# JOOQ LoggerListener extensive DEBUG logging

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, logging, jooq

I need, for performance reasons, get rid of `org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener` `DEBUG` log messages in Spring Boot application running inside Docker. None of the Spring Boot options like (Docker) env variable `LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_JOOQ=INFO` in `docker-compose.yml` or Java system property `-Dlogging.level.org.jooq=INFO` passed to docker container in `entry.sh` do not remove these DEBUG messages reporting query execution details. Both option have been checked at Docker container level.

Even custom `logback-perf.xml` conf file, as in https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example/src/main/resources/logback.xml with `DEBUG->INFO`, pointed by `LOGGING_CONFIG` env var from `docker-compose.yml` does not prevent these debug messages. I have verified that the custom `logback-perf.xml` conf file is in use by changing appender patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to remove those messages *in jOOQ directly*, is to specify `Settings.executeLogging = false`, [see here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-execute-logging/).

Obviously, there are also ways to set up loggers correctly, but I cannot see what you did from your description, or why that failed.

Comment: Thank you @LukasEder. Custom JOOQ configuration really works. In the meantime we've found why Spring Boot ignored all other logging level changes. Spring detects the `DEBUG` environment variable, even if empty, and sets the logging level regardless of any other configuration. The non-empty `DEBUG` env var was used to add remote debug options. Changing the name to `REMOTE_DEBUG` solves the issue

Comment: @TomasBahnik: Thanks for documenting this here. You can answer your own question here on Stack Overflow, in fact. This way, other readers of this question will find your solution even more easily, in case they have the same problem.